# What is the best way to translate "To do list"?

Tags: english-to-german, expression

The closest translation I can find so far is `Aufgabenliste` which is more literally "Task List".

Is there a more commonly used, native way to express the common english phrase "To do list" when using it as a heading or label of such a list?

Comment: _Agenda_ oder _(noch) zu erledigen_ oder _ausstehende Aufgaben_

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do not know what the difference between a task list and a to-do list is, but you can use:

> Aufgabenliste
>   Abarbeitungsliste
>   Liste der offenen Aufgaben
>   [To-do-Liste](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/To_do_Liste) (we borrowed that word)

Comment: Thanks! In definition there is certainly little to no difference between "Task list" an "To do list", however in common usage you rarely see "Task list" and "To do list" is the much more familiar usage. Informally at least.

Comment: To-Do-Liste and Aufgabenliste are the most common ones. You can use either.

Comment: What about "Aufgabenzettel", especially if one really means this sheet of paper?

Comment: That's a suitable translation, too, @AlexanderGalkin.

Comment: *Aufgabenzettel* makes me think of the sheet of paper with your homework on it that gets handed out at university rather than a to-do list.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [John Smithers' answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3421), this is another term I've heard being used:

> Pendenzenliste

I'd say there is a minor difference concerning the connotation:

> Aufgabenliste: a list of generic to-do items
>
> Pendenzenliste: a list of pending items

Comment: Are you from Switzerland? I've never heard this term and when looking it up, Duden tells me it is used in Switzerland: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pendenz